# Wicked gem Rails - How to create a new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

The [Building Partial Objects Step by Step](https://github.com/schneems/wicked/wiki/Building-Partial-Objects-Step-by-Step) page on the Wicked Gem Wiki explains how to create an object step by step with `wicked`.

But how do I have to create a new `Product` object?

Do i have to do that in the new action in the `ProductsController` ?
And where do i have to redirect to ?

Comment: I have exactly the same question. Any luck in finding an answer elsewhere?

Answer (score 5):

The following statement is given in the [Building Partial Objects Step by Step](https://github.com/schneems/wicked/wiki/Building-Partial-Objects-Step-by-Step) page.

`This also means to get to the create action we don't have a product_id yet so we can either create this object in another controller and redirect to the wizard, or we can use a route with a placeholder product_id such as [POST] /products/building/build in order to hit this create action.`

You can create the object in another controller and redirect to wizard or use a route with a placeholder to hit the create action.

Comment: That doesn't explain how to create a route with a placeholder, nor does it explain what the path should look like.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample from my app which worked for me

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    user_background = resource.build_user_background
    user_background.save
    user_background_build_path(user_background.id, :first_step_name)
  end

end
```

This creates the `UserBackground` object and then passes the user to the first step of the wicked controller with the newly created object id.