# Wicked gem - how to create a new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, wicked-gem

I have created a wizard form using Wicked gem and it works great for editing existing records. But I can't figure out how to create a new record using this wizard form.

Quotations from documentation[Building Partial Objects Step by Step](https://github.com/schneems/wicked/wiki/Building-Partial-Objects-Step-by-Step):

"This also means to get to the create action we don't have a product_id yet so we can either create this object in another controller and redirect to the wizard, or we can use a route with a placeholder product_id such as [POST] /products/building/build in order to hit this create action."

I tried to do it the same way as described above, but the problem is, that Campaign.create creates empty object without ID needed for Wicked wizard form.

```
def create
  @campaign = Campaign.create
  redirect_to wizard_path(steps.first, :campaign_id => @campaign.id)
end
```

I am using Rails 4.0.4. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Did you ever figure out a method for setting the ID?

Comment: I am having a problem with this!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wicked gem Rails - How to create a new object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14662279/wicked-gem-rails-how-to-create-a-new-object)